# Checking Objects and Values using Is Operator in Python

Tags: python, string, boolean

Why is this:

```
x = str(input("Enter a string: "))       #input "cat"
y = str(input("Enter another string: ")) #input "cat"
print(x is y) #Outputs False
```

Not the same as this:

```
x = "cat"
y = "cat"
print(x is y) #Outputs True
```

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69589747/python-why-is-the-is-operator-returning-true-in-this-situation

Comment: Why do you think *it should be the same*? Which of these outcomes is unexpected? Do you understand what the `is` operator does?

Comment: In the first snippet, x and y asks for a string. In the other, it was already set to same strings. I don't quite understand how the first snippet returns false when the second returns true.

Comment: @ChristianSalinas why? Do you **understand what the `is` operator does**? Again, *what were you expecting*?

Comment: I understand that `is` checks if the objects point to the same memory location. But, I was expecting `True` to return in the first snippet. I guess I overlook the `input` as well that's why it was confusing to me.

Comment: @ChristianSalinas wait wait wait. Why did you expect *either* of these to print `True`? If anything, it should be *unexpected* that `True` ever came up. Indeed, the fact that it happens to be `True` in the second case is *not something you can depend on*, and is completely based on implementation details

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25758019/5014455) from one of the linked duplicates, I think it addresses everything in very good detail

Answer (score 1):

The `is` operator in python is used to check if two objects point to the same memory location.

In the second case, when python runs, for optimization purposes both x and y point to the same memory location. However, in the first case, x and y are not defined until the user inputs a value during run time. So, they're both allocated memory in different locations.

Comment: "This has already been answered many times on SO." then it should be flagged as a duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://realpython.com/python-is-identity-vs-equality/) *Real Python* article:

> The `==` operator compares the value or equality of two objects, whereas the Python `is` operator checks whether two variables point to the same object in memory. In the vast majority of cases, this means you should use the equality operators == and !=, except when you’re comparing to None.

```py
>>> x = None
>>> y = None
>>> id(x); id(y)
4389651888
4389651888
>>> x is y
True
```

`==` calls the `__eq__` method of an object, `is` checks whether the `id()` of two objects is equal (memory address).

The rest of the article I linked is really informative; it talks about how Python will give the same id to small integers by default, and that you can use the `sys.intern()` method to ensure string variables point to the same object in memory as well.